# How to parse this protocol with an arduino?

Tags: arduino, pwm, signal, analysis, reverse-engineering

I'm analyzing a signal from my building's intercom system to my tenant station. Intercom has two wires, +24V/0.27ma, and ground. Every 10 seconds, the system sends a "heartbeat" signal to the tenant station which looks like this.

[image]

Signal goes from 24V (idle) to alternating between ~18V and ~30V. It holds the voltage by segments of 100us, and this looks like some kind of PWM signal, maybe a packet with header + data + checksum?

My questions are:

1. Is this a common communication protocol? I don't know much about electronics.
2. How would I go about analyzing this signal, given that it's 10khz and that Arduino analog reads are much slower than that?

My goal would be to process it under this form: LOW for 1 frame, HIGH for 5 frames, etc, then reverse engineer it.

Comment: 10 kHz is too fast made me chuckle

Comment: Try implementing interrupts on falling/rising edge. You will also need to block the DC signal, attenuate the signal from `12V` to `5V` and bias it to `2.5V`

Comment: Looks like RS232, idle, start, 8 data bits, stop - but what the bytes mean is anybody's guess. I presume you've searched for documentation?

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do you explain the non-square waveform though? Looks like the signal slowly dives to the 24V baseline during long frames. I would expect RS232 to be perfectly square. After using a DC block, it goes between -9V/+9V but also goes into the -3/+3V band. I wouldn't be able to pipe this into a MAX232, right?

Comment: The waveform distortion may be a measurement artefact (e.g. poor connection) or some cable issue. On closer inspection, the signal looks more like a TTL level RS232 signal than standard RS232 but the voltage differential appears too high, but the waveform seems to fit (ignoring the distortion)